# VS 2010 Deployment without Web Deploy

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

With VS 2008 I always used Web Deployment Projects to build to three different environments. It is maybe not the best solution, since I still have to xcopy the built files to the server, but it is simple.

Now with VS 2010 it looks promising, but it also looks complicated. My hosting provider doesn't have Web Deploy, the newest feature and the flagship technology for deployment in VS 2010.

My question is how can I just build for each environment and copy the files over to the server? Using the Build Deployment Package will create the ZIP file and when I extract it, it will output so many files and a confusing folder structure. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a release of Web Deployment Projects for Visual Studio 2010. The Beta 1 release `[is available][1]` from the Microsoft Download Centre.

This was [mentioned on the Visual Web Developer Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/14/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-beta-avail-now.aspx) too.

Comment: I already downloaded this. thanks
so no other way to use Web Deploy without IIS 7 and Web Deploy on the server.